# How to embed a custom bitmap font into website using CSS

Tags: css, embedded-fonts

How can I embed a custom bitmap font into my website using CSS? I've tried the following but it just reverts to the fallback font:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'AgendaSemibold';
src: url('Agenda-Semibold.bmap') format('bitmap');
}
```

I'm trying to call it using the usual way:

```
font-family: 'AgendaSemibold', Times New Roman, Sans-Serif;
```

The font has been uploaded to my webspace but it's just reverting to Times.