# How could I embed a raster font in a website?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Let's say the font is a .fon or .fnt, could I embed these in a webpage? Is there a particular format for embedding a raster font?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed a custom bitmap font into website using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354935/how-to-embed-a-custom-bitmap-font-into-website-using-css)

Comment: The problem with that duplicate is that is has a link only answer.

Comment: I checked that question already, it didn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this today. But while the technology is still in its infancy, [multicolor fonts are coming to browsers](http://www.pixelambacht.nl/2014/multicolor-fonts). This would allow you to convert those bitmap formats to plain OpenType TTFs. All but Microsoft's proposal would allow for bitmap/raster fonts to be used.

This technology already works in current versions Firefox on all platforms. Support in other browsers is coming.

Answer (score 0):

[Support](http://caniuse.com/fontface) to font embedding via `@font-face` covers EOT (IE only),  WOFF, SVG, and TTF/OTF. So the font files would need to be converted to at least one of these formats (and, for best browser coverage, all of them).

Comment: Ok thank you, so do you know of a website/program that can convert a raster font to those formats? Or I also have a bitmap image of the font if that can be converted.